# How does routing work (for this example) in QtWebEngine?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtwebengine

I hope this is not an obvious question, but I can not find an answer to it. It is very easy to find a single page Qt5 QtWebEngine example, but I can not find a multi page one. I have this in my qml:

```
WebEngineView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    url: "index.html"
}
```

How can I declare that the engine responds to a get-request for instance for a "newPage.html"? or a separate style.css file?